# React Native Pressable component error - onPress is not a function

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass a function to my `Pressable` component:

```
const Component = (navigateTo) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Pressable onPress={navigateTo}>
```

I am passing the function:

```
  const navigateToMyCoverScreen = () => {
    const screenToNavigate =
      userType === "Lite" ? AppRoutes.one.Name : AppRoutes.two.Name;

    navigate(screenToNavigate);
  };

     <Component navigateTo={navigateToMyCoverScreen} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Forget to wrap the "navigateTo" curl bracket like this

```
const Component = ({navigateTo}) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Pressable onPress={navigateTo}>
```

or If u dont want to use curly bracket, use props like this :

```
const Component = (props) => {

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pressable onPress={props.navigateTo}>
```